# using aws batch to schedule dynamic jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I have an use case where (though a web interface) an user submits a request.  Part of this request includes the time at which the request should be fulfilled.  For example if the fulfilment time is tomorrow then the request should be fulfileed only tomorrow and not immediately.  I'm trying to figure out the best AWS service to use for this and I came accross AWS batch.  Is this the correct service to use or is there something else I should consider.

Can AWS Batch be triggered on schedule to run an AWS Lambda.  For example if two users submit two requests, the first one to fulfil tomorrow and the second one to fulfil in two days time, can we use AWS batch to call the lambda tomorrow and again call the lambda in two days time ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case. We ended up building a custom system for scheduling Batch jobs:

1. When a user submits his task, the task's parameters and schedule is stored in database – parameters in one collection and the schedule in another. (We use MongoDB but if we did not, DynamoDB would be a good candidate.)
2. There's an EventBridge rule which triggers every minute and calls the scheduler Lambda function. The function scans the task schedules collection and looks for tasks that are due and submits them as Batch jobs. (In our use case, we allow periodic jobs so the schedule entry is not deleted after submitting the job, but only the next run date is updated.)

We opted-out for using EventBridge for directly scheduling the Batch jobs as there's a 300 rules service quota.